# Loading products in modal window rails and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Been working on my first rails application. I am using bootstrap modal on a page. What i am trying to achieve is to display a list of products (from database) on the main page with button which opens a modal window containing details of that particular product. I have tried making each modal for each product but it makes the main page load very slow and heavy. Is there anyway for using One Modal and then updating the values inside the modal with respect to the product button clicked.

Comment: Updating values in a Bootstrap modal is the same as updating them for the rest of the page - the modal is just a div. Update its contents, and they show up when the modal is displayed.

Comment: Yes . i have tried that but how can i attach the trigger with the link_to button which updates the modal div before displaying modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load the contents of the modal using ajax

In [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), it shows you how to remotely load content into a modal using ajax

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="remote.html" data-target="#modal">Click me</a>
```

and the href attribute is your individual product content

There is also a bootstrap extension as well, [bootstrap-modal](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/), there is an example of using ajax with jquery.load (scroll down, it's in the middle), there is even a [gem](https://github.com/vicentereig/bootstrap-modal-rails) for it.